# count total number of duplicate word in a sentence

Tags: java

I want to count total number of duplicate word or repeating word in a sentence. Here I am able to print the words but not able to count  those words.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Duplicate {  
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
       
        String input = "Big black bug bit a big black dog on his big black nose";  
        //Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
         //System.out.println("Enter the sentence");
        
        //String input = scanner.nextLine();
        
        int count; 
        int counter=0;
         
        //Converts the string into lowercase  
        input = input.toLowerCase();  
          
        //Split the string into words using built-in function  
        String words[] = input.split(" ");  
          
        System.out.println("Duplicate words in a given string : ");   
        for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {  
            count = 1;  
            for(int j = i+1; j < words.length; j++) {  
                if(words[i].equals(words[j])) {  
                    count++;  
                    //Set words[j] to 0 to avoid printing visited word  
                    words[j] = "0";  
                    counter=counter+1;
                    
                }  
            }  
              
            //Displays the duplicate word if count is greater than 1  
            if(count > 1 && words[i] != "0")  {
                System.out.println(words[i]);
            }
            
        } 
         
        System.out.println("Total Duplicate words in a given string : " +counter);
}  
}
```

I expect output :--

> Duplicate words in a given string :  big black
>
> Total Duplicate words in a given string : 2

The output is coming like :

> Duplicate words in a given string :  big black
>
> Total Duplicate words in a given string : 10

Total count is showing 10 instead of 2.

Comment: Is this homework or can you use [Guava's Multiset](https://www.baeldung.com/guava-multiset)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the increment to `counter` to here should work:

```
if (count > 1 && !words[i].equals("0")) {
    counter++;
    System.out.println(words[i]);
}
```

Instead of in the second loop. Right now `counter` will be incremented every time you find another occurrence of a duplicate. Moving `counter` below will only increment it when you've discovered that there is a duplicate word.

That said, this approach can be simplified by using a [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to count the number of times each word appears.

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `HashMap` instead of 2 for loops as below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  

    String input = "Big black bug bit a big black dog on his big black nose";  
    HashMap<String, Integer> dupCount = new HashMap<>();

       //Converts the string into lowercase  
    input = input.toLowerCase();  

    //Split the string into words using built-in function  
    String words[] = input.split(" ");  


    System.out.println("Duplicate words in a given string : ");   
    for(int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) { 
        if(dupCount.containsKey(words[i])){
            int cnt = dupCount.get(words[i]);
            cnt = cnt + 1;
            dupCount.put(words[i], cnt);        
        }else{
            dupCount.put(words[i], 0);
        }
    }

    for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> test : dupCount.entrySet()){
        if(test.getValue() > 1)  {
            System.out.println("Duplicate words in a given string : " +test.getKey() + " : " + test.getValue());
        }
    }
}
```

In this case last statement will be printed each time a duplicate occurs you can modify it as per your need.